# How to put an array in hash of arrays without using its reference

Tags: arrays, perl

I am using perl for my programming.
I stuck in a situation were there is a loop which intakes from a file and thus splits into a array named data i.e @data.
and i have an hash %hash for adding array elements directly without a reference.

in this case for while loop, the $key holds a single @data info in its memory and puts it of all lines called after it. Kindly provide with perfect solutions.

```
while (loop in which line by line of file is been readed) {
    @data= split (/\|/, $line, -1);
    %hash{$key}= \@data;
}
```

Comment: what is the key to your hash?what is $key holding?

Comment: I do not understand your question, but maybe my guess is correct: You have to copy the @data array as follows `$hash{$key} = [@data]` or declare `my @data` in the loop, otherwise all hash values point to the same array.

Comment: In programming there are no perfect solutions

Comment: Another solution would be to declare the array inside the loop body → `my @data = split ...`. Assuming your `$key` simply is the first field of the line, you could also do `my ($key, @data) = split ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use YAML 'Dump';

my %results;

sub bad {
  my @data;
  while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    @data = split /\|/, $_, 2;
    $results{bad}{$data[0]} = \@data;
  }
}

sub good {
  while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @data = split /\|/, $_, 2;
    $results{good}{$data[0]} = \@data;
  }
}

sub good_also {
  while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    /^([^|]+)/;  # pretend we're getting the key some other way
    $results{good_also}{$1} = [split /[|]/, $_, 2]
  }
}

my $data_pos = tell DATA;
bad;
seek DATA, $data_pos, 0; good;
seek DATA, $data_pos, 0; good_also;

print Dump(\%results);

say "bad purchase: ", join '|', @{$results{bad}{purchase}};
say "bad location: ", join '|', @{$results{bad}{location}};
say "bad when: ", join '|', @{$results{bad}{when}};

__DATA__
purchase|apples
location|Fiesta
when|today
```

Output:

```
---
bad:
  location: &1
    - when
    - today
  purchase: *1
  when: *1
good:
  location:
    - location
    - Fiesta
  purchase:
    - purchase
    - apples
  when:
    - when
    - today
good_also:
  location:
    - location
    - Fiesta
  purchase:
    - purchase
    - apples
  when:
    - when
    - today
bad purchase: when|today
bad location: when|today
bad when: when|today
```